# How do i avoid variable from getting printed on nodejs service console?

Tags: node.js, export, local-variables

How do i avoid Local variable from getting printed on the nodejs service console?

validation.js

```
function getHash(){
  var hash = [];
  hash = //some logic to create hash
  return hash;
}

var hashTable= getHash();

exports.validateRequest= function(request, path, httpMethod){
  var status= validate(hashTable,request); //some logic to validate request using hashTable
  return status;
}
```

Every time an API call is triggered, my code invokes the `validateRequest` method but the `hashTable` remains unchanged all the time. I intend to calculate hashTable once and re-use it. Hence i'm using a local variable so that getHash() is called only once during initialisation.

This works fine as far as my implementation is concerned. But the problem is when i start my Node.js service, the hashTable get printed on the service console as below. How can i get rid of this?

[Nodejs service console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6AqAt.png)

```
//code to create hashTable 
function createHashTable() {
  var apis= require('../config/api.js'),
      apiTable = [];
  for (key in apis) {
    //some simple array split and value comparison operations
    apiTable.push({ name: key, path: new RegExp(apis[key].spec.path), method: apis[key].spec.method })
  }
 return apiTable;
}
```

Comment: can you provide the code when you actually create the hash?

Comment: @FredMaggiowski I have added the code to create hash in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The issues was with `createHashTable` function. I had appended `*` to some of the paths in `apis[key].spec.path`. This being a 'path' variable, `*` will make it a invalid path. Hence the error was getting printed on the console. After correcting the code to

`var path=apis[key].spec.path + '/*';
 apiTable.push({ name: key, path: new RegExp(path), method: apis[key].spec.method })`

There is no error in the hash table generation. So my console looks clean.